# Positioning Image and Navbar on top of eachother

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, menubar

I've been working on this forever but can't find a way to do it. 
So I have a bootstrap column, with a White Ribbon (image) and I'm trying to position the Bootstrap navigation bar to lie on top of this White Ribbon.

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-offset-4">
                    <img src="./Images/WhiteRibbon.png" id="WhiteRibbonImg">



                    <nav class="navbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


                            <li class="dropdown" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">

                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu Item</a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Suspendisse tincidunt</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Suspendisse tincidunt</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Suspendisse tincidunt</a></li> 
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Right now it just shows the image with Navbar below it. I've tried to absolutely position them both with relavance to the parent column / row, but it's not working.

IDEAL:
[image]

What I have right now:
[image]

Comment: have you tried to put img element inside nav element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/* Position the containing element */
div.col-lg-offset-4 { //Create a class & don't use bootstraps class name 
  position: relative; 
} 

img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: By giving the `div` a `relative` position and it's containing elements (`img` and `nav`) an `absolute` position, you can position both of the elements **relative** to their parent element which is the `div`.
`z-index` allows you to stack elements on top of each other. The one with a higher number is stacked on top of the other.  

 I used `right: 0px` to place the _right edge_ of the elements `0px` away from the `div`'s right edge but you can use other position properties `top`, `bottom` and `left` to get your desired look. Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try making it absolute in your CSS

```
display: absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `z-index: 2` to the CSS style for your list/list items. 
z-index specifies the stacking of elements. Elements with a higher value rest on top of lower value elements. Every element has a default value of 1.